# Python: pywhatkit.core.exceptions.UnableToAccessApi when using PyWhatKit for converting text to handwriting

Tags: python

Our teacher showed us some code on how to convert text to handwriting.
The code is as follows:

```py
import pywhatkit as kt

text = "Hello SoftUni!!"
kt.text_to_handwriting(text, rgb=(196, 213, 0))
```

But when I run it in PyCharm I got the following error:

```
File "C:\Programming\Python\Projects\FirstStepsLab\TextToHandwriting.py", line 4, in <module>
    kt.text_to_handwriting(text, rgb=(196, 213, 0))
  File "C:\Programming\Python\Projects\ProgramFlow\venv\Lib\site-packages\pywhatkit\handwriting.py", line 22, in text_to_handwriting
    raise exceptions.UnableToAccessApi("Unable to access Pywhatkit api right now")
pywhatkit.core.exceptions.UnableToAccessApi: Unable to access Pywhatkit api right now
```

Can you help put why I got this error and how to fix the code?

I tried searching on Google but only found much more difficult solutions including the cv2 library.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Install `pywhatkit` older version and it will work.

Try using the following code:

```bash
pip install pywhatkit==4.6
```

Comment: still issue is comming